# Simple-Navigation Rails 3 - Primary and Sub Navigation Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, uinavigationbar

I have a simple-navigation for my View :

```
SimpleNavigation::Configuration.run do |navigation|
  navigation.active_leaf_class = 'active'
  navigation.items do |primary|
    primary.item :profile,'Profile', edit_user_path do |profile|
      profile.item :basic, 'Basic Information', edit_user_path
      profile.item :additional, 'Addditional Details', additional_details_user_path
      profile.dom_class = 'nav nav-list'
    end
  primary.item :notifications, 'Notifications', notification_preferences_user_path do |notification|
    notification.item :notificatin_preference, 'Notification Preferences', additional_details_user_path
    notification.dom_class = 'nav nav-list'
  end
```

primary.dom_class = 'nav nav-pills'
end
end

Additional details is another method which is not related to edit, so it doesnt highlight the primary profile link when i click on that link. How can I et it right?  MY User resources in routes are like this :

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :network
    put :peer_tagged_expertise_list
    get :qr_code
    get :qr_code_image
    get :about_you
    get :timeline
    get :network_tagcloud
    get :user_tagcloud
    get :settings
    get :notification_preferences
    get :additional_details
  end
  collection do
    get :test
    get :followers
  end
  resource :networks
end
```

Comment: You're trying to use bootstrap, am I right?

Comment: @daemonsy : Yes Twitter BootStrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer after getting more information**

The structuring code used in Simple Navigation does not automatically adjust your routes.

In order to get `/users/1/profile/additional_details`, your route should include the nesting of user => profile => additional details.

The path should be something like `additional_details_user_profile_path` when generated. This fixes the URL problem, but I'm not sure if it will fix your highlighting issue with Bootstrap.

**Old Answer**
For simple navigation, use

```
navigation.active_leaf_class="active"
```

to set your active nav item class. For Bootstrap, the item should be classed as `active`.

```
SimpleNavigation::Configuration.run do |navigation|
  navigation.active_leaf_class = "active" # Added this line
  navigation.items do |primary|
    primary.item :profile,'Profile', edit_user_path do |profile|
      profile.item :basic, 'Basic Information', edit_user_path
      profile.item :additional, 'Addditional Details', additional_details_user_path
      profile.dom_class = 'nav nav-list'
    end
  primary.item :notifications, 'Notifications', notification_preferences_user_path do |notification|
    notification.item :notificatin_preference, 'Notification Preferences', additional_details_user_path
    notification.dom_class = 'nav nav-list'
  end
```

Comment: I have navigation.active_leaf_class="active"
already just missed to add it. My issues is that additional_details_user_path page doesnt highlight the primary link Profile since it is totally a different action. What can I do about that ? It doesn come as http://localhost:3000/en/users/1/profile/additional_details but http://localhost:3000/en/users/1/additional_details

Comment: If you want a link like localhost:3000/en/users/1/profile/additional_details, it's an issue with `nested routes`? From my guess, an default generated route like additional_details_user_path should generate a route like `/users/:id/additional_details`. Can you post more code from your route?

Comment: resources :users do
      member do
        get :network
        put :peer_tagged_expertise_list
        get :qr_code
        get :qr_code_image
        get :related_profiles
        get :tags
        get :network_timeline
        get :badges
        get :about_you
        get :timeline
        get :network_tagcloud
        get :user_tagcloud
        get :settings
        get :notification_preferences
        get :additional_details
      end
This is the routes for User model and here additional_details and edit(basic_info) are two different actions

Comment: Please post back on top to put in good code formatting, to save everyone's eyes =)

Comment: Sorry, is there a `profile` member (or match, scope etc) inside your route? it's required for the `profile/additional_details` route to work. Simple Nav does not take care of the routing for you.